# How can I create this function from coefficients and selected features created by glmnet

Tags: r

I am using a penalised model for gene selection. From this model, I get the coefficients and the selected features. To use these same coefficients in other dataset, I have manually created this function:

```
validation<- function(x) {
  -0.6907010*x$feature0-0.6907010*x$feature1+0.7578129*x$feature2...}
```

Where x is the validation dataset and the number is the coefficient obtained from glmnet.
However, I would like to create this same function automatically, as copying and pasting numbers sometimes leads to errors.
I tried to do something with paste0, but doesn't work:

```
predict_surv <- function(x) {myResults$coefs * paste0('X$', myResults$features)}
```

A reproducible example is:

```
library(glmnet)
X<-matrix(rnorm(100*10),100,10);X[51:100,]<-X[51:100,]+0.5;
#artificiallyintroducedifferenceincontrolcases
rownames(X)<-paste0("observation",1:nrow(X));
colnames(X)<-paste0("feature",1:ncol(X));


y<-factor(c(rep(1,50),rep(0,50)));#binaryoutcomeclasslabely

##Performlogisticmodelfit:
fit1<-cv.glmnet(X,y,family="binomial",nfolds=5,type.measure="auc");

myCoefs<-coef(fit1,s="lambda.min");myCoefs[which(myCoefs!=0)]
#coefficients:interceptincluded
##[1]1.4945869-0.6907010-0.7578129-1.1451275-0.7494350-0.3418030-0.8012926-0.6597648-0.5555719
##[10]-1.1269725-0.4375461
 myCoefs@Dimnames[[1]][which(myCoefs!=0)]#featurenames:interceptincluded
    ##[1]"(Intercept)""feature1""feature2""feature3""feature4""feature5""feature6"
    ##[8]"feature7""feature8""feature9""feature10"
    
##Assebleintoadata.frame
myResults<-data.frame(features=myCoefs@Dimnames[[1]][which(myCoefs!=0)],#interceptincludedcoefs=myCoefs[which(myCoefs!=0)]#interceptincluded)
myResults

##featurescoefs
##1(Intercept)   1.4945869
##2feature1   -0.6907010
##3feature2   -0.7578129
##4feature3   -1.1451275
##5feature4   -0.7494350
```

Comment: Can you just use `predict()` with the `newdata` argument?

Comment: Or `coef(fit)` with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @DanY no, Ican't. As far as I understand, if I use predict, the function recalculates the coefficients, and this is something I don't want, since I want to use those same coefficients.

Comment: `coef(fit)` gives you the same table as my example but with all the coefficients. Including those I don't want to use.

Comment: That is incorrect - predicting uses an already fitted model. It doesn't re-fit the model and generate new coefficients. (That's what the `glmnet()` function does - `predict()` is a different function.)

Comment: Wait - you're trying to use the fitted coefficients, but only some of them?? Why? That's a terrible way to handle missing data.

Comment: How are you deciding what coefficients to "keep / use"?  It's statistically invalid (ie, a terrible idea) to just say "nah, I don't like coef 3 so I'm throwing that one out".

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, I'm using fitted coefficients. What I am trying to see is whether the features of that sample are validated in another dataset. 
In my case, the features are genes that affect the progression of the cancer and I want to see if those same genes with those same coefficients can be validated in totally different patients dataset. I don't have much knowledge of statistics, but that's the way I've been told I have to do it by the biostatisticians at the centre where I work.

Comment: @Enrique, that doesn't sound correct. Do you just want to multiply the non-zero coefficients? or only some that you selected.. I think this is the part everyone is unclear about

Comment: @StupidWolf The non-zero coefficients as I think I did: `which(myCoefs!=0)`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself very well. I just want to create a function(x) that contains the coefficients and features obtained from glmnet with the same format as the first function so I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is still a better choice. Subset the coefficients down to what you want, then `your_new_model_matrix %*% your_coef` does that operation. You don't need the `validation` function - you just need to matrix multiply a new model matrix with the coefficients (making sure the columns are in the correct coefficient order)

Comment: But how can I select the features? Because in the new validation dataset I have more that 20.000 genes, and I just want to use and multiply those genes that glmnet has selected.

Comment: Based on the names. You already have `myCoefs@Dimnames[[1]][which(myCoefs!=0)]` - get rid of the intercept: `myFeatures = myCoefs@Dimnames[[1]][which(myCoefs!=0)][-1]`